# Does Win 7 or Snow Leopard have a feature similar to Ubuntu's workspace?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard

I really like the workspace feature in Ubuntu because I can have two types of windows, one for entertainment and the other for development.  I also like how I can move programs from one workspace to the next.  I was playing around with Spaces on OS X 10.5 but couldn't replicate Ubuntu's workspace behaviour.  Does anyone know if Windows 7 or Snow Leopard has a similar workspace fuctionality?

Comment: What does Ubuntu Workspaces to that OSX Spaces does not?

Comment: You can use different instances of Firefox and other apps between two workspaces.  The application feels like they are stuck in one workspace in 10.5 and you can't really move them to the next space smoothly.  You can also right click on an app and move it to the other workspace, I couldn't do that in 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has virtual desktops, which might be similar.

See the following article for a comparison of several virtual desktop managers : ["Best Free Virtual Desktop Manager"](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-virtual-desktop-manager.htm). My personal favorite is Dexpot.

Comment: Do we have those third party apps because Windows or OS X don't have this kind of feature natively implemented in the OS?

Comment: On Windows, actually all these 3rd party products are implemented using Microsoft technology. These managers are just simply so much better than Microsoft's. This article describes Microsoft's best effort, Desktops : http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/window-on-windows/?p=791. Just compare this with Dexpot.

Answer (score 0):

The 'hidden feature' of Snow Leopard is a host of tweaks to how Spaces and Exposé behave. Even if you weren't happy with Spaces/Exposé in Leopard you may be very pleased with them in Snow Leopard.

Here's a [brief video showing a bit of window management in Spaces mode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7gb1mC599Y) (the top of the screen is clipped off in the video).

You can zoom-out to spaces mode (via a hot-corner or keystroke) and drag individual windows across (adding Exposé mode in addition to Spaces zoom as shown in the video to see every window), or hold the Command key and all the windows belonging to that application will move across.

Or while zoomed in you can drag a window to the edge of the screen, hold a moment, and your view will slide across to the adjacent space bringing the window with you. A keystroke (in my case, ctrl-1 through ctrl-4) to switch spaces while dragging a window will have the same effect.